# Accessing events defined on constructor - is this approach good?

Tags: javascript

I have a class that manages tabs:

```
function TabsManager() {}
```

When performing certain operations like adding or removing tabs it broadcasts events, for example, `active-tab-change`. I want to make it as explicit as possible what events are supported by this class, so I define them like this:

```
TabsManager.EVENTS = {
    ACTIVE_TAB_CHANGE: "active-tab-change"
}
```

When subscribing to tabs manager events, I can specify the event name like this:

```
tabsManager.on("active-tab-change", function(){});
```

However, this approach is error prone since I can misspell event name. So I use enumeration-like object `EVENTS`:

```
 tabsManager.on(TabsManager.EVENTS.ACTIVE_TAB_CHANGE, function(){});
```

The problem here is that if I use `dependency injection` I don't have a direct reference to object constructor, so I've used this approach:

```
 tabsManager.on(tabsManager.constructor.EVENTS.ACTIVE_TAB_CHANGE, function(){});
```

I've never seen this approach used before, so I'm curios whether it's a feasible approach and whether it's already been used in js frameworks/libraries?

Comment: Can't you inject the constructor as a dependency? Or even the `EVENTS` enum?

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, I can, but then it could seem redundant if I can access `EVENTS` through `.constructor` property. Since you asked I assume you'd prefer constructor injection over using `.constructor` property?